# Why GCC does not use LOAD(without fence) and STORE+SFENCE for Sequential Consistency?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11, x86

Here are four approaches to make Sequential Consistency in x86/x86_64:

1. LOAD(without fence) and STORE+MFENCE
2. LOAD(without fence) and LOCK XCHG
3. MFENCE+LOAD and STORE(without fence)
4. LOCK XADD(0) and STORE(without fence)

As it is written here: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html

> C/C++11 Operation x86 implementation
>
> - Load Seq_Cst:    MOV (from memory)
> - Store Seq Cst:   (LOCK) XCHG //
>     alternative: MOV (into memory),MFENCE

Note: there is an alternative mapping of C/C++11 to x86, which instead of locking (or fencing) the Seq Cst store locks/fences the Seq Cst load:

> - Load Seq_Cst:    LOCK XADD(0) // alternative: MFENCE,MOV (from memory)
> - Store Seq Cst:   MOV (into memory)

**GCC 4.8.2(GDB in x86_64)** uses first(1) approach for [C++11-std::memory_order_seq_cst](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), i.e. LOAD(without fence) and STORE+MFENCE:

```
std::atomic<int> a;
int temp = 0;
a.store(temp, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
0x4613e8  <+0x0058>         mov    0x38(%rsp),%eax
0x4613ec  <+0x005c>         mov    %eax,0x20(%rsp)
0x4613f0  <+0x0060>         mfence
```

As we know, that MFENCE = LFENCE+SFENCE. Then this code we can rewrite to this: `LOAD(without fence) and STORE+LFENCE+SFENCE`

**Questions:**

1. Why do we need not to use LFENCE here before LOAD, and need to use LFENCE after STORE (because LFENCE make sense only before LOAD!)?
2. Why GCC does not use approach: LOAD(without fence) and STORE+SFENCE for std::memory_order_seq_cst?

Comment: What do you mean with LFENCE before LOAD? In your source code you assign a zero value to a, which is a store and not a load and then it makes no difference if lfence is called before or after the mov instruction.

Comment: @smossen  I mean definitely that LFENCE make sense only before LOAD, and LFENCE don't make any sense after STORE **in any cases**.

Comment: std::memory_order_seq_cst implies lfence+sfence. This triggers synchronization of all other variables that are not declared atomic, thus not calling lfence+sfence (or mfence) when the standard says so would change semantics. If you have a variable "int b;" and another thread has assigned b=1 and then called sfence, this will be visible to this thread first when this thread calls lfence (which could be done by storing a new value into the atomic variable a).

Comment: @smossen and Alex: sfence + lfence is still not a StoreLoad barrier (http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/ explains how StoreLoad barriers are special).  x86 has a strong memory model where LFENCE and SFENCE only exist for use with `movnt` loads/stores, which are weakly ordered as well as bypassing the cache.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705169/does-the-intel-memory-model-make-sfence-and-lfence-redundant.

Answer (score 7):

The only reordering x86 does (for normal memory accesses) is that it can potentially reorder a load that follows a store.

SFENCE guarantees that all stores before the fence complete before all stores after the fence.  LFENCE guarantees that all loads before the fence complete before all loads after the fence.  For normal memory accesses, the ordering guarantees of individual SFENCE or LFENCE operations are already provided by default.  Basically, LFENCE and SFENCE by themselves are only useful for the weaker memory access modes of x86.

Neither LFENCE, SFENCE, nor LFENCE + SFENCE prevents a store followed by a load from being reordered.  MFENCE does.

The relevant reference is the Intel x86 architectural manual.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstring>

std::atomic<int> a;
char b[64];

void seq() {
  /*
    movl    $0, a(%rip)
    mfence
  */
  int temp = 0;
  a.store(temp, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

void rel() {
  /*
    movl    $0, a(%rip)
   */
  int temp = 0;
  a.store(temp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

With respect to the atomic variable "a", seq() and rel() are both ordered and atomic on the x86 architecture because:

1. mov is an atomic instruction
2. mov is a legacy instruction and Intel promises ordered memory semantics for legacy instructions to be compatible with old processors that always used ordered memory semantics.

No fence is required to store a constant value into an atomic variable. The fences are there because std::memory_order_seq_cst implies that all memory is synchronized, not only the memory that holds the atomic variable.

The effect can be demonstrated by the following set and get functions:

```
void set(const char *s) {
  strcpy(b, s);
  int temp = 0;
  a.store(temp, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

const char *get() {
  int temp = 0;
  a.store(temp, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  return b;
}
```

strcpy is a library function that might use newer sse instructions if such are available in runtime. Since sse instructions were not available in old processors there is no requirement on backwards compatibility and memory order is undefined. Thus the result of a strcpy in one thread might not be directly visible in other threads.

The set and get functions above uses an atomic value to enforce memory synchronization so that the result of strcpy becomes visible in other threads. Now the fences matters, but the order of them inside the call to atomic::store is not significant since the fences are not needed internally in atomic::store.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a link where said that "**sse instructions** ... is no requirement on backwards compatibility and **memory order is undefined**"?

Comment: That was my own summary of a quite comprehensive document...
[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual
Combined Volumes 3A, 3B, and 3C: System Programming Guide](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf)
Section 8.2 is about memory ordering. Note that x86_64 is IA-32e in the Intel world while IA-64 is the Itanium.

Comment: `std::memory_order_seq_cst` must not provide SC(sequential consistency) for `strcpy(b, s);` because **SC provide it only for atomic operations that are so tagged `std::memory_order_seq_cst`**.   "Atomic operations tagged std::memory_order_seq_cst not only order memory the same way as release/consume ordering (everything that happened-before a store in one thread becomes a visible side effect in the tread that did a load), but, in addition, establish **a single total modification order of all atomic operations that are so tagged**." http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: SC is not provided between atomic operations. Agree to that. But if thread X calls strcpy at time t0 and makes an atomic store at time t1, thread Y makes an atomic load at time t2, the result of the strcpy should be visible to thread Y at time t3 (provided t0<t1<t2<t3 and memory_order_seq_cst). This is why the fences are required.

Comment: And your arguments are valid and identical for the **acquire-release** semantic, but then another question: why GCC does not put fences to `std::memory_order_acq_rel`? In this line `std::string* p  = new std::string("Hello");` class `std::string` can use SSE-instructions in an example of source code for **Release-Acquire ordering**, and it will not work in GCC for acquire-release? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: Which atomic operation did you use with std::memory_order_acq_rel?

Comment: Who need it. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Where didn't gcc put fences with memory_order_acq_rel?

Comment: Everywhere, in any cases. Look at the link for orders `std::memory_order_release` and `std::memory_order_acquire`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18637536/1558037 For `memory_order_acq_rel` you self can using GCC+GDB try to disassemble: http://ideone.com/i8wBag  Or read this: "On strongly-ordered systems (**x86**, SPARC, IBM mainframe), **release-acquire** ordering is automatic for the majority of operations. **No additional CPU instructions** are issued for this synchronization mode, only certain compiler optimizations are affected" - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: The example as written is wrong and has a data race.  Two seq_cst stores don't synchronize and thus don't force the get function to see the effects of the strcpy in the set.  If you make the seq_cst store into a load, and check that it sees the 0, then this will be okay.

Comment: If `strcpy` or `memcpy` uses NT stores, it must end with an `sfence` inside the library function.  This is required for a valid C11 implementation, because C11 / C++11 require an atomic release store to order non-atomic operations.  Existing implementations use pure `mov` without fences for `mo_release` stores.  (Also, as briand points out, the seq_cst store in the reader is pointless.  You need an acquire operation, and you need to check the value to make sure `strcpy` actually finished in the producer thread, i.e. check a data_ready flag.)

Answer (score 6):

SFENCE + LFENCE is **not** a StoreLoad barrier (MFENCE), so the premise of the question is incorrect.  (See also my answer on another version of this same question from the same user [Why is (or isn't?) SFENCE + LFENCE equivalent to MFENCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627969/why-is-or-isnt-sfence-lfence-equivalent-to-mfence/50322404#50322404))

---

- SFENCE can pass (appear before) earlier loads.  (It's just a StoreStore barrier).
- LFENCE can pass earlier stores.  (Loads can't cross it in either direction: LoadLoad barrier).
- Loads can pass SFENCE (but stores can't pass LFENCE, so it's a LoadStore barrier as well as a LoadLoad barrier).

LFENCE+SFENCE doesn't include anything that stops a store from being buffered until after a later load.  MFENCE **does** prevent this.

[Preshing's blog post](http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/) explains in more detail and with diagrams how StoreLoad barriers are special, and has a practical example of working code that demonstrates reordering without MFENCE.  Anyone that's confused about memory ordering should start with that blog.

x86 has a [strong memory model](http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/) where every normal store has release semantics, and every normal load has acquire semantics.  [This post has the details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106843/gccs-reordering-of-read-write-instructions/22142537#22142537).

LFENCE and SFENCE [only exist for use with `movnt` stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705169/does-the-intel-memory-model-make-sfence-and-lfence-redundant), which are weakly ordered as well as bypassing the cache.  (And later SSE4.1 `movntdqa` loads from WC memory are also weakly ordered, but not from WB memory so it won't bypass cache for cacheable memory.)  LFENCE is in practice primarily useful a barrier to out-of-order *exec* of non-memory instructions, like `rdtsc`.  (And long after it was introduced, to block speculative exec in some cases for Spectre mitigation.)

---

In case those links ever die, there's even more info in my [answer on another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32394427/224132).

Answer (score 5):

`std::atomic<int>::store` is mapped to the compiler intrinsic `__atomic_store_n`.  (This and other atomic-operation intrinsics are documented here: [Built-in functions for memory model aware atomic operations](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).)  The `_n` suffix makes it type-generic; the back-end actually implements variants for specific sizes in bytes.  `int` on x86 is AFAIK always 32 bits long, so that means we're looking for the definition of `__atomic_store_4`.  [The internals manual for this version of GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gccint/Standard-Names.html) says that the `__atomic_store` operations correspond to machine description patterns named `atomic_store‌mode`; the *mode* corresponding to a 4-byte integer is "SI" ([that's documented here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gccint/Machine-Modes.html)), so we are looking for something called "`atomic_storesi`" in the x86 machine description.  And that brings us to [config/i386/sync.md](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/i386/sync.md;h=9e5835662e1c690e25bd6f7c0ff6a3077e280c9d;hb=gcc-4_8-branch#l198), specifically this bit:

```
(define_expand "atomic_store<mode>"
  [(set (match_operand:ATOMIC 0 "memory_operand")
        (unspec:ATOMIC [(match_operand:ATOMIC 1 "register_operand")
                        (match_operand:SI 2 "const_int_operand")]
                       UNSPEC_MOVA))]
  ""
{
  enum memmodel model = (enum memmodel) (INTVAL (operands[2]) & MEMMODEL_MASK);

  if (<MODE>mode == DImode && !TARGET_64BIT)
    {
      /* For DImode on 32-bit, we can use the FPU to perform the store.  */
      /* Note that while we could perform a cmpxchg8b loop, that turns
         out to be significantly larger than this plus a barrier.  */
      emit_insn (gen_atomic_storedi_fpu
                 (operands[0], operands[1],
                  assign_386_stack_local (DImode, SLOT_TEMP)));
    }
  else
    {
      /* For seq-cst stores, when we lack MFENCE, use XCHG.  */
      if (model == MEMMODEL_SEQ_CST && !(TARGET_64BIT || TARGET_SSE2))
        {
          emit_insn (gen_atomic_exchange<mode> (gen_reg_rtx (<MODE>mode),
                                                operands[0], operands[1],
                                                operands[2]));
          DONE;
        }

      /* Otherwise use a store.  */
      emit_insn (gen_atomic_store<mode>_1 (operands[0], operands[1],
                                           operands[2]));
    }
  /* ... followed by an MFENCE, if required.  */
  if (model == MEMMODEL_SEQ_CST)
    emit_insn (gen_mem_thread_fence (operands[2]));
  DONE;
})
```

Without going into a great deal of detail, the bulk of this is a C function body that will be called to generate the low-level "[RTL](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gccint/RTL.html)" intermediate representation of the atomic store operation.  When it's invoked by your example code, `<MODE>mode != DImode`, `model == MEMMODEL_SEQ_CST`, and `TARGET_SSE2` is true, so it will call `gen_atomic_store<mode>_1` and then `gen_mem_thread_fence`.  The latter function always generates `mfence`.  (There is code in this file to produce `sfence`, but I believe it is only used for explicitly-coded `_mm_sfence` (from `<xmmintrin.h>`).)

The comments suggest that *someone* thought MFENCE was required in this case.  I conclude that *either* you are mistaken to think a load fence is not required, *or* this is a missed optimization bug in GCC.  It is *not*, for instance, an error in how you are using the compiler.

Comment: Thank you! But what is the logic to use the LFENCE after the STORE? (STORE+MFENCE = STORE+LFENCE+SFENCE)

Comment: I can't help you with that part of the question, sorry.  You would maybe have better luck asking this on the mailing list `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`.

Comment: MFENCE is required for sequential consistency; see my answer.