# Does it make any sense to use the LFENCE instruction on x86/x86_64 processors?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, atomic, memory-barriers

Often in internet I find that `LFENCE` makes no sense in processors x86, ie it does nothing , so instead `MFENCE` we can absolutely painless to use `SFENCE`, because `MFENCE` = `SFENCE` + `LFENCE` = `SFENCE` + `NOP` = `SFENCE`.

But if `LFENCE` does not make sense, then why we have four approaches to make Sequential Consistency in x86/x86_64:

1. `LOAD` (without fence) and `STORE` + `MFENCE`
2. `LOAD` (without fence) and `LOCK XCHG`
3. `MFENCE` + `LOAD` and `STORE` (without fence)
4. `LOCK XADD` ( 0 ) and `STORE` (without fence)

Taken from here: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html

As well as performances from Herb Sutter on page 34 at the bottom: https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=4E86B0CF20EF15AD!24884&app=WordPdf&wdo=2&authkey=!AMtj_EflYn2507c

If `LFENCE` did not do anything, then the approach (3) would have the following meanings: `SFENCE + LOAD and STORE (without fence)`, but there is no point in doing `SFENCE` before `LOAD`. Ie if `LFENCE` does nothing , the approach (3) does not make sense.

Does it make any sense instruction `LFENCE` in processors x86/x86_64?

**ANSWER:**

**1.** `LFENCE` required in cases which described in the accepted answer, below.

**2.** The approach (3) should be viewed not independently, but in combination with the previous commands. For example, approach (3):

```
MFENCE
MOV reg, [addr1]  // LOAD-1
MOV [addr2], reg  //STORE-1

MFENCE
MOV reg, [addr1]  // LOAD-2
MOV [addr2], reg  //STORE-2
```

We can rewrite the code of approach (3) as follows:

```
SFENCE
MOV reg, [addr1]  // LOAD-1
MOV [addr2], reg  //STORE-1

SFENCE
MOV reg, [addr1]  // LOAD-2
MOV [addr2], reg  //STORE-2
```

And here `SFENCE` makes sense to prevent reordering  STORE-1 and LOAD-2. For this after STORE-1 command `SFENCE` flushes Store-Buffer.

Comment: There are instructions with a "non-temporal hint" which aren't as strongly ordered as the usual load and store; I imagine those may benefit from fencing. (Edit: This is actually mentioned on the page you linked.)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Bottom line (TL;DR): `LFENCE` alone indeed seems useless for memory ordering, however it does not make `SFENCE` a substitute for `MFENCE`. The "arithmetic" logic in the question is not applicable.

---

Here is an excerpt from [Intel's Software Developers Manual, volume 3](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf), section 8.2.2 (the edition 325384-052US of September 2014), the same that I used in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093137/does-x86-sse-instructions-have-an-automatic-release-acquire-order/27302931#27302931)

> - Reads are not reordered with other reads.
> - Writes are not reordered with older reads.
> - Writes to memory are not reordered with other writes, with the following exceptions:
>
>   - writes executed with the CLFLUSH instruction;
>   - streaming stores (writes) executed with the non-temporal move instructions (MOVNTI, MOVNTQ, MOVNTDQ, MOVNTPS, and MOVNTPD); and
>   - string operations (see Section 8.2.4.1).
> - Reads may be reordered with older writes to different locations but not with older writes to the same location.
> - Reads or writes cannot be reordered with I/O instructions, locked instructions, or serializing instructions.
> - Reads cannot pass earlier LFENCE and MFENCE instructions.
> - Writes cannot pass earlier LFENCE, SFENCE, and MFENCE instructions.
> - LFENCE instructions cannot pass earlier reads.
> - SFENCE instructions cannot pass earlier writes.
> - MFENCE instructions cannot pass earlier reads or writes.

From here, it follows that:

- `MFENCE` is a full memory fence for all operations on all memory types, whether non-temporal or not.
- `SFENCE` only prevents reordering of writes (in other terminology, it's a StoreStore barrier), and is only useful together with non-temporal stores and other instructions listed as exceptions.
- `LFENCE` prevents reordering of reads with subsequent reads and writes (i.e. it combines LoadLoad and LoadStore barriers). However, the first two bullets say that LoadLoad and LoadStore barriers are always in place, no exceptions. Therefore `LFENCE` alone is useless for memory ordering.

To support the last claim, I looked at all places where `LFENCE` is mentioned in all 3 volumes of Intel's manual, and found none which would say that `LFENCE` is required for memory consistency. Even `MOVNTDQA` - the only non-temporal load instruction so far - mentions `MFENCE` but not `LFENCE`.

---

**Update: see answers on [Why is (or isn't?) SFENCE + LFENCE equivalent to MFENCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627969/why-is-or-isnt-sfence-lfence-equivalent-to-mfence) for correct answers to the guesswork below**

Whether `MFENCE` is equivalent to a "sum" of other two fences or not is a tricky question. At glance, among the three fence instructions only `MFENCE` provides StoreLoad barrier, i.e. prevents reordering of reads with earlier writes. However the correct answer requires to know more than the above rules; namely, it's important that all fence instructions are ordered with respect to each other. This makes the `SFENCE LFENCE` sequence more powerful than a mere union of individual effects: this sequence also prevents StoreLoad reordering (because loads cannot pass `LFENCE`, which cannot pass `SFENCE`, which cannot pass stores), and thus constitutes a full memory fence (but also see the note (*) below). Note however that order matters here, and the `LFENCE SFENCE` sequence does not have the same synergy effect.

However, while one can say that `MFENCE ~ SFENCE LFENCE` and `LFENCE ~ NOP`, that does not mean `MFENCE ~ SFENCE`. I deliberately use equivalence (~) and not equality (=) to stress that arithmetic rules do not apply here. The mutual effect of `SFENCE` followed by `LFENCE` makes the difference; even though loads are not reordered with each other, `LFENCE` is required to prevent reordering of loads with `SFENCE`.

(*) It still might be correct to say that `MFENCE` is stronger than the combination of the other two fences. In particular, a note to `CLFLUSH` instruction in the volume 2 of Intel's manual says that "`CLFLUSH` is only ordered by the `MFENCE` instruction. It is not guaranteed to be ordered by any other fencing or serializing instructions or by another `CLFLUSH` instruction."

(Update, `clflush` is now defined as strongly ordered (like a normal store, so you only need `mfence` if you want to block later *loads*), but `clflushopt` is weakly ordered, but can be fenced by `sfence`.)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't agree about that "`MFENCE` is **stronger** than `LFENCE+SFENCE`. It's a full memory fence for all operations on all memory types, whether non-temporal or not.". We always can write sequence `MOVNTQ` `SFENCE` `LFENCE` `MOVNTQ` or `MOV [addr], reg` `SFENCE` `LFENCE` `MOV reg, [addr]` for Sequential Consistency. I.e. `LFENCE+SFENCE` - similarly a full memory fence for all operations on all memory types, whether non-temporal or not.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It happens to be more complicated; I rewrote the answer with additional details.

Comment: Thank for your clarification, yes I agree, i.e. if we use `SFENCE` instead of `MFENCE` for Sequential Consistency then what can happen: `MOV [addr1], reg` `SFENCE` `MOV reg, [addr2]` --> `MOV [addr1], reg` `MOV reg, [addr2]` `SFENCE` --> `MOV reg, [addr2]` `MOV [addr1], reg` `SFENCE`. I.e. it is logical, we got reordering  Store <-> Load. But can it really happen? If so, then there must be a mechanism that includes a command fence, what is this mechanism? Everywhere write that the `LFENCE` does not do anything, ie no such mechanism. There is Store Buffer, but no Load Buffer.

Comment: And yes, thank for your note, I agree, that `LFENCE`+`SFENCE` != `SFENCE`+`LFENCE` :) Because for first can happen next: `MOV [addr1], reg` `LFENCE` `SFENCE` `MOV reg, [addr2]` --> `LFENCE` `MOV [addr1], reg` `MOV reg, [addr2]` `SFENCE` --> `LFENCE` `MOV [addr1], reg` `MOV reg, [addr2]` `SFENCE` --> `LFENCE` `MOV reg, [addr2]` `MOV [addr1], reg` `SFENCE`. I.e. we got reordering Store <-> Load, ie do not get Sequential Consistency. I fixed this in my question.

Comment: Ie the main question now, is reordering of `SFENCE`  `MOV reg, [addr]` --> `MOV reg, [addr]` `SFENCE` possible only in theory or perhaps in reality? And if possible, in reality, what mechanisms, how does it work? For example reordering of `MOV [addr], reg` `LFENCE` -->  `LFENCE` `MOV [addr], reg` provided by mechanism - Store Buffer, which reorders Store - Loads for performance increase, and beacause `LFENCE` does not prevent to it .

Comment: Possibly the new main question might deserve a separate SO question.

Comment: Thank you! Ok, I created new separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627969/what-mechanism-disables-the-lfence-to-make-impossible-reordering

Comment: It sounds to me that `SFENCE`/`LFENCE` pair implements release/acquire C++11 memory ordering semantics. Does it not?

Comment: LFENCE does appear to implement acquire semantics since it acts as a LoadLoad and a LoadStore barrier. SFENCE is ONLY a StoreStore barrier(and that too only NT and other weaker operations defined by x86,CFLUSH etc).Release semantics require the properties of a LoadStore and a StoreStore barrier. See https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/. For release semantics, an LFENCE + SFENCE(in that order) will likely do it. I assume this will only be useful with WC regions and NT memory accesses.

Answer (score 9):

Consider the following scenario - this is the critical case where speculative load execution can theoretically harm sequential consistency

initially [x]=[y]=0

```
CPU0:                              CPU1: 
store [x]<--1                      store [y]<--1
load  r1<--[y]                     load r2<--[x]
```

Since x86 allows loads to be reordered with earlier stores to different addresses, both loads may return 0's. Adding an lfence alone after each store wouldn't prevent that, since they only prevent reordering within the same context, but since stores are dispatched after retirement you can have both lfences and both loads commit before the stores are performed and observed.

An **mfence** on the other hand would force the stores to perform, and only then allow the loads to be executed, so you'll see the updated data on at least one context.

As for **sfences** - as pointed out in the comment, in theory it's not strong enough to prevent the load from reordering above it, so it might still read stale data. While this is true as far as the memory official ordering rules apply, I believe that current implementation of x86 uarch makes it slightly stronger (while not committing to do so in the future, I guess). According to [this description](http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-tm-alt/2/):

> Because of the strong x86 ordering model, the load buffer is snooped
>   by coherency traffic. A remote store must invalidate all other copies
>   of a cache line. If a cache line is read by a load, and then
>   invalidated by a remote store, the load must be cancelled, since it
>   potentially read invalid data. The x86 memory model does not require
>   snooping the store buffer.

Therefore, any load not yet committed in the machine should be snoopable by stores from other cores, thereby making the **effective** observation time of the load at the **commit** point, and not the *execution* point (which is indeed out of order and may have been performed much earlier). Commit is done in order, and therefore the load should be observed after previous instructions - making lfences pretty much useless as I said above in the comments, since the consistency can be maintained the same way without them.
This is mostly speculation, trying to explain the common conception that lfences are meaningless in x86 - I'm not entirely sure where it originated and if there are other considerations at hand - would be happy for any expert to approve / challenge this theory.

*All the above applies only for WB mem types of course*

Comment: SFENCE cannot be used to fix this example, because a load can migrate up across SFENCE.  The example requires MFENCE to fix.

Comment: @ArchD.Robison, in practice, the load would have to retire after any previous instruction, and during that time a store from the other thread would be able to snoop it - I think this would cause re-execution but i'm not entirely sure, so I fixed the answer as you suggested - thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the fix.  I recommend coding against the architectural guarantees since the micro-architects are always looking for clever and mysterious ways to speed things up.

Comment: @Leeor What do you mean by "but since stores are dispatched after retirement"? Do you mean the result of the store is saved to the store buffer and then "disptached" to the L1 cache later?

Comment: @user997112, yes. The result of the store can be calculated speculatively, but the store itself must not be exposed and visible externally until it is committed (i.e. - all instructions up to it are known to be on the correct path and non faulting). Some machines can handle such stores in the cache perhaps using special bits to mark them as speculative (in case a snoop comes along), but the common solution is to keep the store in the buffer until it has committed. Also note that in architectures where stores are ordered like x86, dispatching from the buffer must also be done in-order.