# Does standard C++11 guarantee that memory_order_seq_cst prevents StoreLoad reordering of non-atomic around an atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, standards

Does standard C++11 guarantee that `memory_order_seq_cst` prevents StoreLoad reordering around an atomic operation for non-atomic memory accesses?

As known, there are 6 `std::memory_order`s in C++11, and its specifies **how regular, non-atomic** memory accesses are to be ordered around an atomic operation - Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++ 2016-07-12: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf

> § 29.3 Order and consistency
>
> § 29.3 / 1
>
> The enumeration **memory_order** specifies the detailed **regular
>   (non-atomic) memory** synchronization order as defined in 1.10 and may
>   provide for operation ordering. Its enumerated values and their
>   meanings are as follows:

Also known, that these 6 memory_orders prevent some of these reordering:

[image]

But, does `memory_order_seq_cst` prevent StoreLoad reordering around an atomic operation for **regular, non-atomic** memory accesses or only for other atomic with the same `memory_order_seq_cst`?

I.e. to prevent this StoreLoad-reordering should we use `std::memory_order_seq_cst` for both STORE and LOAD, or only for one of it?

```
std::atomic<int> a, b;
b.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst); // Sequential Consistency
a.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst); // Sequential Consistency
```

---

About Acquire-Release semantic is all clear, it specifies exactly non-atomic memory-access reordering across atomic operations: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

---

To prevent StoreLoad-reordering we should use `std::memory_order_seq_cst`.

Two examples:

1. `std::memory_order_seq_cst` for both STORE and LOAD: **there is `MFENCE`**

StoreLoad can't be reordered - GCC 6.1.0 x86_64: https://godbolt.org/g/mVZJs0

```
std::atomic<int> a, b;
b.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst); // can't be executed after LOAD
a.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst); // can't be executed before STORE
```

2. `std::memory_order_seq_cst` for LOAD only: **there isn't `MFENCE`**

StoreLoad can be reordered - GCC 6.1.0 x86_64: https://godbolt.org/g/2NLy12

```
std::atomic<int> a, b;
b.store(1, std::memory_order_release); // can be executed after LOAD
a.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst); // can be executed before STORE
```

Also if C/C++-compiler used alternative mapping of C/C++11 to x86, which flushes the Store Buffer before the LOAD: `MFENCE,MOV (from memory)`, so we must use `std::memory_order_seq_cst` for LOAD too: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html As this example is discussed in another question as approach (3): [Does it make any sense instruction LFENCE in processors x86/x86_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316124/does-it-make-any-sense-instruction-lfence-in-processors-x86-x86-64?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I.e. we should use `std::memory_order_seq_cst` for both STORE and LOAD to generate `MFENCE` guaranteed, that prevents StoreLoad reordering.

Is it true, that `memory_order_seq_cst` for atomic Load or Store:

- specifi Acquire-Release semantic - prevent: LoadLoad, LoadStore, StoreStore reordering around an atomic operation for **regular, non-atomic** memory accesses,
- but prevent StoreLoad reordering around an atomic operation **only for other atomic** operations with  the same `memory_order_seq_cst`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, standard C++11 **doesn't** guarantee that `memory_order_seq_cst` prevents **StoreLoad** reordering of `non-atomic` around an `atomic(seq_cst)`.

Even standard C++11 **doesn't** guarantee that `memory_order_seq_cst` prevents **StoreLoad** reordering of `atomic(non-seq_cst)` around an `atomic(seq_cst)`.

Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++ 2016-07-12: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf

- There shall be a single total order S on all `memory_order_seq_cst` operations - C++11 Standard:

> § 29.3
>
> 3
>
> **There shall be a single total order S on all memory_order_seq_cst
>   operations, consistent with the “happens before” order and
>   modification orders for all affected locations**, such that each
>   memory_order_seq_cst operation B that loads a value from an atomic
>   object M observes one of the following values: ...

- But, any atomic operations with ordering weaker than `memory_order_seq_cst` hasn't sequential consistency and hasn't single total order, i.e. non-`memory_order_seq_cst` operations can be reordered with `memory_order_seq_cst` operations in allowed directions - C++11 Standard:

> § 29.3
>
> 8 [ Note: **memory_order_seq_cst ensures sequential consistency
>   only for a program that** is free of data races and **uses exclusively
>   memory_order_seq_cst operations. Any use of weaker ordering will
>   invalidate this guarantee** unless extreme care is used. In particular,
>   memory_order_seq_cst fences ensure a total order only for the fences
>   themselves. Fences cannot, in general, be used to restore sequential
>   consistency for atomic operations with weaker ordering specifications.
>   — end note ]

---

Also C++-compilers allows such reorderings:

1. **On x86_64**

Usually - if in compilers seq_cst implemented as barrier after store, then:

`STORE-C(relaxed);` `LOAD-B(seq_cst);` can be reordered to `LOAD-B(seq_cst);` `STORE-C(relaxed);`

Screenshot of Asm generated by GCC 7.0 x86_64: https://godbolt.org/g/4yyeby

Also, theoretically possible - if in compilers seq_cst implemented as barrier before load, then:

`STORE-A(seq_cst);` `LOAD-C(acq_rel);` can be reordered to `LOAD-C(acq_rel);` `STORE-A(seq_cst);`

2. **On PowerPC**

`STORE-A(seq_cst);` `LOAD-C(relaxed);` can be reordered to `LOAD-C(relaxed);` `STORE-A(seq_cst);`

Also on PowerPC can be such reordering:

`STORE-A(seq_cst);` `STORE-C(relaxed);` can reordered to `STORE-C(relaxed);` `STORE-A(seq_cst);`

If even atomic variables are allowed to be reordered across atomic(seq_cst), then non-atomic variables can also be reordered across atomic(seq_cst).

Screenshot of Asm generated by GCC 4.8 PowerPC: https://godbolt.org/g/BTQBr8

---

More details:

1. **On x86_64**

`STORE-C(release);` `LOAD-B(seq_cst);` can be reordered to `LOAD-B(seq_cst);` `STORE-C(release);`

[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures](http://www.intel.com/Assets/en_US/PDF/manual/253668.pdf)

> 8.2.3.4 Loads May Be Reordered with Earlier Stores to Different Locations

I.e. x86_64 code:

```
STORE-A(seq_cst);
STORE-C(release); 
LOAD-B(seq_cst);
```

Can be reordered to:

```
STORE-A(seq_cst);
LOAD-B(seq_cst);
STORE-C(release);
```

This can happen because between `c.store` and `b.load` isn't `mfence`:

**x86_64 - GCC 7.0**: https://godbolt.org/g/dRGTaO

C++ & asm - code:

```
#include <atomic>

// Atomic load-store
void test() {
    std::atomic<int> a, b, c;
    a.store(2, std::memory_order_seq_cst);          // movl 2,[a]; mfence;
    c.store(4, std::memory_order_release);          // movl 4,[c];
    int tmp = b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);    // movl [b],[tmp];
}
```

It can be reordered to:

```
#include <atomic>

// Atomic load-store
void test() {
    std::atomic<int> a, b, c;
    a.store(2, std::memory_order_seq_cst);          // movl 2,[a]; mfence;
    int tmp = b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);    // movl [b],[tmp];
    c.store(4, std::memory_order_release);          // movl 4,[c];
}
```

---

Also, Sequential Consistency in x86/x86_64 can be implemented in four ways: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html

> 1. `LOAD` (without fence) and `STORE` + `MFENCE`
> 2. `LOAD` (without fence) and `LOCK XCHG`
> 3. `MFENCE` + `LOAD` and `STORE` (without fence)
> 4. `LOCK XADD` ( 0 ) and `STORE` (without fence)

- 1 and 2 ways: `LOAD` and (`STORE`+`MFENCE`)/(`LOCK XCHG`) - we reviewed above
- 3 and 4 ways: (`MFENCE`+`LOAD`)/`LOCK XADD` and `STORE` - allow next reordering:

`STORE-A(seq_cst);` `LOAD-C(acq_rel);` can be reordered to `LOAD-C(acq_rel);` `STORE-A(seq_cst);`

---

2. **On PowerPC**

`STORE-A(seq_cst);` `LOAD-C(relaxed);` can be reordered to `LOAD-C(relaxed);` `STORE-A(seq_cst);`

Allows Store-Load reordering (**Table 5 - PowerPC**): http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2010.06.07c.pdf

> Stores Reordered After Loads

I.e. PowerPC code:

```
STORE-A(seq_cst);
STORE-C(relaxed); 
LOAD-C(relaxed); 
LOAD-B(seq_cst);
```

Can be reordered to:

```
LOAD-C(relaxed);
STORE-A(seq_cst);
STORE-C(relaxed); 
LOAD-B(seq_cst);
```

**PowerPC - GCC 4.8** : https://godbolt.org/g/xowFD3

C++ & asm - code:

```
#include <atomic>

// Atomic load-store
void test() {
    std::atomic<int> a, b, c;       // addr: 20, 24, 28
    a.store(2, std::memory_order_seq_cst);          // li r9<-2; sync; stw r9->[a];
    c.store(4, std::memory_order_relaxed);          // li r9<-4; stw r9->[c];
    c.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);              // lwz r9<-[c];
    int tmp = b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);    // sync; lwz r9<-[b]; ... isync;
}
```

By dividing `a.store` into two parts - it can be reordered to:

```
#include <atomic>

// Atomic load-store
void test() {
    std::atomic<int> a, b, c;       // addr: 20, 24, 28
    //a.store(2, std::memory_order_seq_cst);            // part-1: li r9<-2; sync;
    c.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);              // lwz r9<-[c];
    a.store(2, std::memory_order_seq_cst);          // part-2: stw r9->[a];
    c.store(4, std::memory_order_relaxed);          // li r9<-4; stw r9->[c];
    int tmp = b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);    // sync; lwz r9<-[b]; ... isync;
}
```

Where load-from-memory `lwz r9<-[c];` executed earlier than store-to-memory `stw r9->[a];`.

---

Also on PowerPC can be such reordering:

`STORE-A(seq_cst);` `STORE-C(relaxed);` can reordered to `STORE-C(relaxed);` `STORE-A(seq_cst);`

Because PowerPC has weak memory ordering model - allows Store-Store reordering (**Table 5 - PowerPC**): http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2010.06.07c.pdf

> Stores Reordered After Stores

I.e. on PowerPC operations Store can be reordered with other Store, then previous example can be reordered such as:

```
#include <atomic>

// Atomic load-store
void test() {
    std::atomic<int> a, b, c;       // addr: 20, 24, 28
    //a.store(2, std::memory_order_seq_cst);            // part-1: li r9<-2; sync;
    c.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);              // lwz r9<-[c];
    c.store(4, std::memory_order_relaxed);          // li r9<-4; stw r9->[c];
    a.store(2, std::memory_order_seq_cst);          // part-2: stw r9->[a];
    int tmp = b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);    // sync; lwz r9<-[b]; ... isync;
}
```

Where store-to-memory `stw r9->[c];` executed earlier than store-to-memory `stw r9->[a];`.

Comment: Informative answer (+1), but one thing I cannot agree with.. 
Where you say: -- _Also, theoretically possible - if in compilers seq_cst implemented as barrier before load, then:
LOAD-C(acq_rel); STORE-A(seq_cst); can be reordered to STORE-A(seq_cst); LOAD-C(acq_rel);_ -- 
That is not possible since the `load` is an acquire barrier (preventing operations that follow it from moving up) and the `store` is a release barrier (preventing operations that precede it from moving down). It's per the standard, not just the implementation.

Comment: @LWimsey  Thank you! I fixed it. It should be `STORE-A(seq_cst);` `LOAD-C(acq_rel);` can be reordered to `LOAD-C(acq_rel);` `STORE-A(seq_cst);`   - In the second half of the answer was written correctly, but in the first half of the answer - I mixed up in places.

Answer (score -2):

The `std::memory_order_seq_cst` guarantees there is no reordering by either compiler nor cpu. In this case the same memory order as if only one instruction where executed at a time.

But the compiler optimization confuses the issues, if you turn off -O3 then the fence is [there](https://godbolt.org/g/VYQ7F2).

The compiler can see that in your test program with -O3 that there are no consequence of the mfence as the program is too simple.

If you ran it on an Arm on the other hand like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:armhfg482,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-O3',source:'%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%0A//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0Avoid+test()+%7B%0A++++std::atomic%3Cint%3E+a,+b%3B%0A++++b.store(1,+std::memory_order_release)%3B+//+can+be+executed+after+LOAD%0A++++a.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)%3B+//+can+be+executed+before+STORE%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3) you can see the barriers `dmb ish`.

So if your program is more complex you might see the `mfence` in this part of the code but not if the compiler can analyse and reason that it is not needed.

Comment: No, x86_64 doesn't give these guarantees, i.e. x86_64 can reorder the first STORE and next LOAD if there is no `MFENCE`: Reads may be reordered with older writes [different locations], Herb Sutter - page 35: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=4E86B0CF20EF15AD!24884&app=WordPdf&authkey=!AMtj_EflYn2507c And as we see, **`std::memory_order_seq_cst` for LOAD doesn't produce `MFENCE`**, then it doesn't give us a guarantee that StoreLoad will not be reordered: https://godbolt.org/g/2NLy12

Comment: Your right `• Reads may be reordered with older writes [different locations].`. My conclusion that the example is too simple tho still stands.

Comment: "_The std::memory_order_seq_cst guarantees there is no reordering by either compiler nor cpu_" no ordering of what exactly?

Comment: The compiler isn't optimizing away an unneeded `mfence` (unfortunately GCC doesn't do that even if you write back-to-back seq_cst stores or fences).  It's just that `.load(seq_cst)` doesn't need a fence instruction.  On top of x86's hardware model (program order + a store buffer with store forwarding), either seq_cst stores or loads need a barrier.  Compiler devs chose stores, leaving us with cheap seq_cst loads.

Comment: The `mfence` as part of the store is because `atomic<T>::store()` is written in C++ with a `memory_order` parameter.  At `-O0`, constant propagation doesn't happen so the order arg to [`__atomic_exchange_n()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) isn't a compile-time constant (that's the `movl    $3, -16(%rbp)` I think), therefore GCC just uses the strongest order, doing a seq_cst store.  This just proves it's basically pointless to look at un-optimized code for inline wrapper functions, or that anti-optimization of C++ promotes everything to seq_cst.