# x86: Are memory barriers needed here?

Tags: x86, memory-model

**In WB-memory, a = b = 0**

```
P1:
a = 1
SFENCE
b = 1

P2:
WHILE (b == 0) {}
LFENCE
ASSERT (a == 0)
```

It is my understanding, that neither the `SFENCE` or `LFENCE` are needed here.

Namely, since, for this memory type, x86 ensures:

1. Reads cant be reordered with older reads
2. Stores cant be reordered with older stores
3. Stores are transitively visible

Comment: Yes, they are not needed. [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316124/does-it-make-any-sense-instruction-lfence-in-processors-x86-x86-64). Although without `SFENCE`, there is no particular guarantee regarding when the processor may decide to make the writes visible. This is mostly not an issue in practice.

Comment: @Kay: Is that pseudo-code for assembly operations, and thus compile-time reordering is not possible?  In C you need a *compiler* barrier, but for x86 no asm barrier instructions are needed here.  **`lfence` and `sfence` asm instructions are no-ops unless you're using NT stores (or NT loads from WC memory, e.g. video RAM).**

Comment: @HadiBrais: `sfence` isn't going to make the stores visible sooner, AFAIK.  It might make the CPU wait while the store buffer drains (but probably only `mfence` does that, to stop StoreLoad reordering).  Stores that were already in the buffer are already committing as fast as possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes You're right. That statement  only holds when the stores are to the same location.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Oh right, we have some evidence that consecutive stores to the same line are merged in the store buffer.  IDK if it would delay commit of the first one, though, if it was at the head of the store buffer.  I'd guess that repeated stores in a loop to the same line would still commit to L1d regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lfence` and `sfence` asm instructions are no-ops unless you're using NT stores (or NT loads from WC memory, e.g. video RAM).  (Actually, [`movntdqa` loads might only be ordered by `mfence` on paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316124/does-it-make-any-sense-instruction-lfence-in-processors-x86-x86-64), not `lfence`.  In which case I don't know when you'd ever use `lfence`.  It was added to the ISA along with `sfence` + `mfence` at the same time as NT stores, before `movntdqa`, possibly just for completeness / in case it was ever needed.)

There is sometimes confusion around this point, because **the C/C++ intrinsics for `lfence` and `sfence` are also compiler barriers**.  That *is* needed in C/C++, but can be had more cheaply with GNU C `asm("":::"memory");` or (to order relaxed-`atomic` operations<sup>1</sup>) `std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel)`.  Restricts [*compile-time* reordering](http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) without making the compiler emit any useless asm barrier instructions.

---

**Run-time reordering is already blocked by the x86 memory model**, except for [StoreLoad reordering](http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/) which requires `mfence` to block.  `lfence` + `sfence` don't add up to `mfence`.  See [Does it make any sense instruction LFENCE in processors x86/x86_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316124/does-it-make-any-sense-instruction-lfence-in-processors-x86-x86-64) and various other SO Q&As about these instructions.

This is why [`std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel)` also compiles to zero instructions on x86](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%0Avoid+fence()+%7B%0A++++std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+full_fence()+%7B%0A++++std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:40.72345390898483,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:67.20318449290413,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g630,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM64+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:67.20318449290413,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:32.79681550709588,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:59.27654609101517,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), but to barriers on weakly-ordered architectures.

---

`lfence` is also a serializing instruction on Intel microarchitectures (but maybe not AMD?).  It has been all along, but Intel recently made this guarantee official so Spectre mitigation techniques could safely use it instead of a much more inconvenient `cpuid`.

---

- Footnote 1:

`atomic_signal_fence` on gcc may also be a compiler barrier for plain non-`atomic` variables; it was last time I checked with gcc  (while `atomic_thread_fence` wasn't), but this is probably just an implementation detail when there aren't any `atomic` variables involved.  When there are `atomic` variables, the compiler knows that those variables may provide ordering that lets other threads access non-atomic variables without UB, so ordering is needed.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the response. As to your comment, yes, this is assembly pseudo-code, so compiler-barriers not needed. Great - I'm glad I'm getting the hang of things. As always, thanks for your time.