# Incorrect use of InterlockedCompareExchange to copy a value atomically?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

**I cannot use C++11 atomics here**

I have a doubt about my use of `InterlockedCompareExchange()` in order to 'atomically' read a variable.

I asked a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50039131/2369597), but what I was doing there was different.  The "exchange" and "comperand" parameters (2nd and 3rd) were 'hard coded' values, i.e. not read from a variable.

Please consider this:

```
    // Copy the connect time
    DWORD dwConnectTime = InterlockedCompareExchange(&msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime, 
                            msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime, 
                            msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime);
```

This is intended to swap the value of `msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime` with the current value of `msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime`,  provided the current value of `msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime` is `msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime`.  The previous value of `msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime` is then returned, *which is what I rely on to 'copy' the value*.

It has just dawned on me though that the reads of `msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime` for the second and third parameters themselves are not guaranteed to be atomic.  Thus, is this code incorrect hence I need to use a locking primitive to copy `msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime`?

Comment: Why are you swapping the current value of a variable with itself?  This should be a no-op.

Comment: This makes no sense. It's almost as if you believe that this one variable can hold two values simultaneously.

Comment: As the linked question shows, I can use this to "atomically read" the value of a variable without risk of getting a torn read or write.  That's what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Reading is atomic if the variable is aligned. And the variable must be aligned to use `InterlockedCompareExchange`. So the accepted answer at the linked question is totally bogus. You seem to be getting ever more confused about issues that really are not that complex.

Comment: What about if I read and write to the same memory location on two different threads each running on a separate core?  Without the `LOCK` instruction surely tearing could happen there...

Comment: If you just want to read a value using Interlocked functions, you can use `InterlockedExchangeAdd()` instead, eg: `DWORD dwConnectTime = InterlockedExchangeAdd(&msgInfo.m_dwConnectTime, 0);` That will return the "previous" value of `m_dwConnectTime` after incrementing it by 0, IOW return its "current" value

Comment: Thanks @Remy Lebeau.  Maybe you could shed some light on my above question?

Comment: you not need any interlocked/lock here. read *dword* value (if it *dword* aligned) already atomic operation. and this not add any synchronization with another threads.

Comment: Yes *reading* might be but what if I read whilst something else is *writing* as can happen on a machine with more than one core???

Comment: @Wad - and so what ? are you understand situation ? atomic read and synchronization with another threads - absolute different things. in anyway you read some value. this value can changed at any time by another thread. but try understand different between atomic read and tread synchronization

Comment: Tearing is impossible for aligned data

Comment: Yes I do understand the difference between an atomic read and thread synchronisation.  I am not trying to protect a critical section of code, I am merely trying to grab a "snapshot" of a variable without having to worry if another CPU is currently writing to it when I try and read it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Pointless to do that. Just read the value directly. Aligned access is atomic.

Comment: [*The Intel486 processor (and newer processors since) guarantees that the following basic memory operations will always be carried out atomically .. Reading or writing a doubleword aligned on a 32-bit boundary*](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p5gtl9k/711-Guaranteed-Atomic-Operations-The-Intel486-processor-and-newer-processors/)

Comment: in case you want *read and change*, say `x = x + 1` here need interlock operation. for read value only(register size, aligned) - not need lock. value after you read it can changed at any time, but this already another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, and the link to your earlier question, this question is motivated by your desire to avoid tearing. Reading from and writing to aligned data is atomic. You are attempting to guard against tearing, but tearing is not possible when the data is aligned. And it is reasonable to assume that your data is aligned because that is a requirement of `InterlockedCompareExchange` and indeed all the `InterlockedXXX` functions.

As such, the question you are asking is something of a non sequitur. It is based on the false premise that tearing can happen with aligned data.

So, you don't need to call `InterlockedCompareExchange` or any other `InterlockedXXX` function in order to avoid tearing, because tearing is only possible when the data is not aligned.

Comment: OK, so what happens if thread A reads and thread B writes (both running on separate cores) at **absolutely, precisely the same time**.  Surely there's potential for a tear there?  Otherwise how is it determined which one goes first?  Isn't that what `LOCK` is for, to prevent anyone else accessing that memory??  If this can't happen, then why do we need `LOCK`?

Comment: @Wad thread A read old or new value. but atomic. note that we try not **change** but only read.

Comment: Perhaps you don't know what tearing is? Tearing is where you have data that straddles a cache line. In order to read, or write it, two memory operations are performed, one on either side of the cache line boundary. If the two read operations interleave with two write operations, then you get partial reads. That's tearing. However, with aligned data, the memory is all within a single cache line and reading and writing are serialized by the memory bus. They can happen in an unpredictable order, but they never tear.

Comment: Right. OK.  I've read that a few times and clearly I didn't know what tearing was.  Thanks for clarifying.  "*reading and writing are serialized by the memory bus*" - is that an answer aimed specifically at me asking what happens if a read and write occur at precisely the same?  In other words, they can't happen at the same time?

Comment: Exactly. Whilst the two processors may reach read and write instructions to the same cache line at the same time, when performing those instructions the memory bus makes sure that they happen one at a time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've posted a follow up at https://stackoverflow.com/q/50121673/2369597, would be greatly appreciative if you could participate.

Comment: This was all covered by Anders answer in the previous question. You should have accepted that answer.