# Interlocked functions and atomicity: still confused

Tags: c, multithreading, c++11, winapi

I'm **still** confused about reading and writing variables atomically.  So sorry in advance to those who have tried to help in previous questions.

I have been told [today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118185/2369597) that there is no need for any `Interlocked` function call when reading and writing a 32bit `long` value, which blows my [previous beliefs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49989123/2369597) out of the window.  Indeed, this backs up what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122.aspx) says

> Simple reads and writes to properly-aligned 32-bit variables are
>   atomic operations. In other words, you will not end up with only one
>   portion of the variable updated; all bits are updated in an atomic
>   fashion

So I then looked at what `atomic_long` in VS2017 does; its `operator=` does an `_InterlockedExchange()` on the current value with the new value.

1. Doesn't this contradict MSDN; if the read/write is atomic, why is this Interlocked function needed?

   On the same MSDN page, we also have

   > Simple reads and writes to properly aligned 64-bit variables are
   >   atomic on 64-bit Windows. Reads and writes to 64-bit values are not
   >   guaranteed to be atomic on 32-bit Windows. **Reads and writes to
   >   variables of other sizes are not guaranteed to be atomic on any
   >   platform.**

   So I then step into `atomic_bool`'s '`operator=`; it executes a `_InterlockedExchange8` call which [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh972656.aspx) tells me is only available on Windows 8 and above.

   This seems to back up the second MSDN quote.
2. If I am using VS 2005 and targeting Windows XP, how would I ensure an atomic read/write of a boolean variable?  Would I have to use a mutex or similar?
3. If a read/write operation is not atomic, that leaves it susceptible to being torn; is that correct?
4. I have read [this PAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35226186/2369597) that says primitive types are not atomic.  Again this contradicts what I have been told in my questions and what MSDN has told me.  Who is correct?

Comment: Windows may only run on processors with atomic operations.  That doesn't mean that all code runs on such processors.

Comment: Seems like you need to understand the [concept of alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Comment: I believe I do understand alignment, but how does that answer any of the 4 questions above?

Comment: For #2, a boolean is 1 byte, so it is always atomic no matter what, but it may require 16-bit or 32-bit operations to read/write a byte value. For #4, primitive types are In of themselves not atomic, as any given multi-byte variable is not guaranteed to be properly aligned in memory. You are responsible for aligning the data that you use. That is where `std::atomic` comes into play, to help ensure that individual variables are aligned when possible, and still "atomic" (such as via mutex) when alignment is not possible.

Comment: The issue isn't tearing. It's compiler and processor optimisations. For instance, the compiler may decide to enregister the variable and then changes won't be seen by the other thread.

Comment: MSDN is talking about particular compilers on particular platforms. The question you linked to in question 4 is not. So they're both correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you quoted an excerpt of the documentation, but not the sentence just following it:

> However, access is not guaranteed to be synchronized. If two threads are reading and writing from the same variable, you cannot determine if one thread will perform its read operation before the other performs its write operation.

That is, while the operations are atomic, ie a thread is guaranteed to write all 4 bytes, before another one is allowed to read it, this doesn't mean that you will be getting the correct values, and the order of execution is unknown.

The Interlocked functions make sure that the operation is carried out in a "transactional" manner, ie it will be atomic and all threads/processors will be getting the last updated values - otherwise this is not guaranteed, because of caching (each CPU/core may maintain a copy in its local cache). The Interlocked functions, as well as all synchronization functions make sure that cache contents are synchronized.

For reading/updating any shared data, yes, you need to employ a mutex. For threads of the same process, a critical section would be preferable, as it's incredibly fast (non-measurable timespans, used them to ensure atomicity in screen-output operations, so i can confirm this).

Comment: Re, "For [accessing] any shared data, yes, you need to employ a mutex." If that was always true, then the atomic_whatever types would serve no purpose.  The truth is, for accessing shared data, you need a _memory barrier_, and you need to ensure that no thread will ever allow any other thread to see an update in an inconsistent, half-done state.  If the update can be passed from one thread to another by changing a single variable, then atomic_whatever provides all the synchronization you need. But, if multiple variables are involved, then you probably need a mutex.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been told today that there is no need for any Interlocked function call when reading and writing a 32bit long value

Because it's not true, at least not that generic.

Only applies to x86, and only if the 32bit value type is aligned, and the variable is actually comitted to memory using a single 32bit wide instruction. Which is commonly the case, but by no means guaranteed, neither the alignment nor the atomic store as the compiler may decide to optimize or can not assume alignment and has therefor to split.

> Doesn't this contradict MSDN; if the read/write is atomic, why is this Interlocked function needed?

An `atomic_long` is not aligned by definition, so an atomic exchange is required for formally correct function.

> This function generates a full memory barrier (or fence) to ensure that memory operations are completed in order.

And that is the other relevant part about atomics - they form a memory barrier.

Which means that neither the compiler nor the processor can re-order memory accesses. If you had e.g. two plain `int` variables which you were writing to independently in the same scope, the compiler would be free to batch or re-order the writes as it likes.

As a side effect, the processor will also attempt to synchronize the caches, so you will see updates made to an atomic variable on another core much faster.

This goes beyond the effect of a plain `volatile` which would also prevent reordering memory access, but could still spend several microseconds waiting for memory writes to be flushed on another core.

> If I am using VS 2005 and targeting Windows XP, how would I ensure an atomic read/write of a boolean variable? Would I have to use a mutex or similar?

Yes. Well, the write is atomic, either way, but you really want the memory barrier if you have been using the boolean to signal that another memory region is now safe to access (e.g. spinlock).

> If a read/write operation is not atomic, that leaves it susceptible to being torn; is that correct?

Not for a `bool`, as it is really just one byte, and I'm not aware of any architecture out there which could tear a variable on the sub-byte level.

For all larger types, yes, as aligment is not guaranteed. And as said before, you don't have any guarantees that the compiler used an atomic instruction, even if it had been "for free".

Comment: Why are you talking about unaligned data. We are talking about aligned data here. And aligned data can't be torn. Which was the previous question. Memory barriers are the issue.

Comment: To add to what @DavidHeffernan said, be careful with assuming that bool is only one byte. [That's implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4897844/5240004) And on Windows there's at least [4 different booleans](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041222-00/?p=36923).

Comment: *An atomic_long is not aligned by definition, so an atomic exchange is required for formally correct function.* Can you clarify what you mean by that please?