# Intel-x86:The interaction between WC, WB and UC Memory

Tags: memory, x86, memory-model

The memory ordering guarantees across different memory regions on x86 architectures are not clear to me. Specifically, the Intel manual states that WC, WB and UC follow different memory orderings as follows.

WC: weak ordering (where e.g. two stores on different locations can be reordered)

WB (as well as WT and WP, i.e. all cacheable memory types): processor ordering (a.k.a TSO, where younger loads can be reordered before older stores on different locations)

UC: strong ordering (where all instructions are executed in the program order and cannot be reordered)

What is not clear to me is the interaction between UC and the other regions. Specifically, the manual mentions:

(A) UC accesses are strongly ordered in that they are always executed in program order and cannot be reordered; and

(B) WC accesses are weakly-ordered and can thus be reordered.

So between (A) and (B) it is not clear how UC accesses and WC/WB accesses are ordered w.r.t. one another.

1a) [UC-store/WC-store ordering] For instance, let us assume that x is in UC memory and y is WC memory. Then in the multi-threaded program below, is it possible to load 1 from y and 0 from x? This would be possible if the two stores in thread 0 can be reordered. (I have put an `mfence` between the two loads hoping that it would stop the loads from being reordered, as it is not clear to me whether WC/UC loads can be reordered; see 3a below)

```
       thread 0       |   thread 1
     store [x] <-- 1  |   load [y]; mfence 
     store [y] <-- 1  |   load [x]
```

1b) What if instead (symmetrically) x were in WC memory and y were in UC memory?

2a) [UC-store/WB-load ordering] Similarly, can a UC-store and a WB-load (on different locations) be reordered? Let us assume that x is in UC memory and z is in WB memory. Then in the multi-threaded program below, is it possible for both loads to load 0? This would be possible if both x and z were in WB emory due to store buffering (or alternatively justified as: younger loads in each thread can be reordered before the older stores as they are on different locations). But since the accesses on x are in UC memory, it is not clear whether such behaviours are possible.

```
       thread 0       |   thread 1
     store [x] <-- 1  |   store [z] <-- 1 
     load [z]         |   load [x]
```

2b) [UC-store/WC-load ordering] What if z were in WC memory (and x is in UC memory)? Can both loads load 0 then?

3a) [UC-load/WC-load ordering] Can a UC-load and a WC-load be reordered? Once again, let us assume that x is in UC memory and y is in WC memory. Then, in the multi-threaded program below, is it possible to load 1 from y and 0 from x? This would be possible if the two loads could be reordered (I believe the two stores cannot be reordered due to the intervening `sfence`; the `sfence` may not be needed depending on the answer to 1a).

```
       thread 0               |   thread 1
     store [x] <-- 1; sfence  |   load [y] 
     store [y] <-- 1          |   load [x]
```

3b) What if instead (symmetrically) x were in WC memory and y were in UC memory?

4a) [WB-load/WC-load ordering] What if in the example of 3a above x were in WB memory (instead of UC) and y were in WC memory (as before)?

4b) What if (symmetrically) x were in WC memory and y were in WB memory?

Comment: Re: load ordering: I think only SSE4.1 `movntdqa` loads can be reordered, and *only* when loading from WC memory.  (Otherwise they're just a slower `movdqa`: [Do current x86 architectures support non-temporal loads (from "normal" memory)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40096894)).  Yes, [MFENCE (or maybe LFENCE) will order it wrt. other loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316124/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-the-lfence-instruction-on-x86-x86-64-processors), or I think it's safe to just use normal loads, and they'll still have their usual acquire semantics even from WC mem.

Comment: Related: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3498683 - *Extending Intel-x86 Consistency and Persistency
Formalising the Semantics of Intel-x86 Memory Types and Non-temporal Stores*.  The introductory section of that paper has some good plain-English descriptions of the various memory types, before getting to formal symbology.

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING: I am ignoring cache coherency in all of this; because it complicates everything and doesn't make any difference to understanding how WB, WT, WP, WC or WC work, or any of the answers.**

Assume you have 4 pieces, like:

```
          ________
         |        |
         | Caches |
         |________|
         /       \
  ______/_       _\__________________
 |        |     |                    |
 |  CPU   |-----|  Physical address  |
 |  core  |     |  space (e.g. RAM)  |
 |________|     |____________________|
        \        /
       __\______/_
      |           |
      | Write     |
      | combining |
      | buffer    |
      |___________|
```

As far as the CPU's core is concerned; everything is always "processor ordering" (total store ordering with store forwarding). **The only difference between WC, WB, WT, WP and UC is the path data takes to go between the CPU core and the physical address space.**

For UC, writes go directly to the physical address space and reads come directly from the physical address space.

For WC, writes go down to "write combining buffer" where they're combined with previous writes and eventually evicted from the buffer (and sent to the physical address space later). Reads from WC come directly from the the physical address space.

For WB, writes go to caches and are evicted from the caches (and sent to the physical address space) later. For WT writes go to both caches and the physical address space at the same time.  For WP writes get discarded and don't reach the physical address space at all. For all of these, reads come from cache (and cause fetch from the physical address space into cache on "cache miss").

There are 3 other things that influence this:

- store forwarding. Any store can be forwarded to a later load within "CPU core", regardless whether the area is supposed to be WC, WB, WT, ... or UC. This means that it's technically wrong to claim that 80x86 has "total store ordering".
- non-temporal stores cause data to go to the write combining buffers (regardless of whether the memory area was originally WB or WT or ... or UC). Non-temporal reads allow a later non-temporal read to occur before an earlier store.
- write fences prevent store forwarding and wait for the write combining buffer to be emptied. Read fences cause CPU to wait until earlier reads complete before allowing later reads. The `mfence` instruction combines the behavior of read fence and write fence. *Note: I lost track of `lfence` - for some/recent CPUs I think it got perverted into hack to help mitigate "spectre" security problems (I think it became a speculative execution barrier rather than just a read fence).*

Now...

1a)

```
  thread 0             |     thread 1
store [x_in_UC] <-- 1  |   load [y_in_WC]; mfence 
store [y_in_WC] <-- 1  |   load [x_in_UC]
```

In this case the `mfence` is irrelevant (the previous `load [y_in_WC]` acts like UC anyway); but the store to `y_in_WC` may take ages to make its way to the physical address space (which isn't important because it's possibly last anyway). It's not possible to load 1 from y and 0 from x.

1b)

```
   thread 0             |     thread 1
 store [x_in_WC] <-- 1  |   load [y_in_UC]; mfence 
 store [y_in_UC] <-- 1  |   load [x_in_WC]
```

In this case, the `store [x_in_WC]` may take ages to make its way to the physical address space; which means that the data loaded by `load [x_in_WC]` may fetch older data from the physical address space (even if the load is done after the store). It's very possible to load 1 from y and 0 from x.

2a)
thread 0             |     thread 1
store [x_in_UC] <-- 1  |   store [z_in_WB] <-- 1
load [z_in_WB]         |   load [x_in_UC]

In this case there's nothing confusing at all (everything happens in the program order; it's just that `store [z_in_WB]` writes to cache and `load [z_in_WB]` reads from cache); and it's not possible for both loads to load 0. *Note: an external observer (e.g. a device watching the physical address space) may not see the store to `z_in_WB` for ages.*

2b)

```
   thread 0             |     thread 1
 store [x_in_UC] <-- 1  |   store [z_in_WC] <-- 1
 load [z_in_WC]         |   load [x_in_UC]
```

In this case the `store [z_in_WC]` may not reach the physical address space until after the `load [z_in_WC]` has occurred (even if the load is done after the store). It is possible for both loads to load 0.

3a)
thread 0             |     thread 1
store [x_in_UC] <-- 1  |   load [y_in_WC]
store [y_in_WC] <-- 1  |   load [x_in_UC]

Same as "1a". It's not possible to load 1 from y and 0 from x.

3b)

```
   thread 0             |     thread 1
 store [x_in_WC] <-- 1  |   load [y_in_UC]
 store [y_in_UC] <-- 1  |   load [x_in_WC]
```

Same as "1b". It's very possible to load 1 from y and 0 from x.

3c)

```
   thread 0             |     thread 1
 store [x_in_WC] <-- 1  |   load [y_in_UC]
 sfence                 |   load [x_in_WC]
 store [y_in_UC] <-- 1  |
```

The `sfence` forces thread 0 to wait for the write combining buffer to drain, so it's not possible to load 1 from y and 0 from x.

4a)

```
   thread 0             |     thread 1
 store [x_in_WB] <-- 1  |   load [y_in_WC]
 store [y_in_WC] <-- 1  |   load [x_in_WB]
```

Mostly the same as "1a" and "3a". The only difference is that the store to `x_in_WB` goes to caches (and the load to `x_in_WB` comes from caches). *Note: an external observer (e.g. a device watching the physical address space) may not see the store to `x_in_WB` for ages.*

4b)

```
   thread 0             |     thread 1
 store [x_in_WC] <-- 1  |   load [y_in_WB]
 store [y_in_WB] <-- 1  |   load [x_in_WC]
```

Mostly the same as "1b" and "3b". *Note: an external observer (e.g. a device watching the physical address space) may not see the store to `y_in_WB` for ages.*

Comment: Intel has always documented `lfence` as an execution barrier (unlike AMD where you're right, the execution-ordering feature was new with Spectre mitigation).  But execution (not memory) ordering was by far the more useful property, e.g. for ordering `rdtsc` around microbenchmarks.  It's very rare that it's useful for ordering SSE4.1 `movntdqa` loads from WC memory, which to my understanding is the only case where it's actually useful for memory ordering.  (Because there are no weakly-ordered loads from other memory types.)

Answer (score 2):

Intel's description of the UC memory type is spread out in numerous places in the Volume 3 of the manual. I'll focus on the parts that are relevant to memory ordering. The main one is from Section 8.2.5:

> The strong uncached (UC) memory type forces a strong-ordering model on memory accesses. Here, all reads and writes to the UC memory
> region appear on the bus and out-of-order or speculative accesses are
> not performed.

This states that UC memory accesses across different instructions are guaranteed to be observed in program order. A similar statement appears in Section 11.3. Both don't say anything about ordering between UC and other memory types. It's interesting to note here that since the global observability of all UC accesses are ordered, it's impossible for a store forwarding to happen from a UC store to a UC load. In addition, UC stores are not coalesced or combined in the WCBs, although they do pass through these buffers because that's the physical path that all requests from the core to the uncore have to traverse.

The following two quotes discuss the ordering guarantees between UC loads and stores and previous or later stores of any type. Emphasis is mine.

> Section 11.3:
>
> **If the WC buffer is partially filled, the writes may be delayed until
> the next occurrence of a serializing event; such as** an SFENCE or
> MFENCE instruction, CPUID or other serializing instruction, **a read or
> write to uncached memory**, an interrupt occurrence, or an execution of
> a LOCK instruction (including one with an XACQUIRE or XRELEASE
> prefix).

This means that UC accesses are ordered with respect to earlier WC stores. Contrast this with WB accesses, which are not ordered with earlier WC stores because they a WB access doesn't cause the WCBs to be drained.

> Section 22.34:
>
> Writes stored in the store buffer(s) are always written to memory in
> program order, with the exception of “fast string” store operations
> (see Section 8.2.4, “Fast String Operation and Out-of-Order Stores”).

This means that stores are always committed from the store buffer in program order, which implies that stores of all types, except WC, across different instructions are observed in program order. A store of any type cannot be reordered with an earlier UC store.

Intel provides no guarantees regarding the ordering of non-UC loads with earlier or later UC accesses (loads or stores), so ordering is architecturally possible.

The AMD memory model is described more precisely for all memory types. It clearly states that a non-UC load can be reordered with an earlier UC store and that a WC/WC+ loads can be reordered with an earlier UC load. So far the Intel and AMD models agree with each other. However, the AMD model also states that a UC load cannot pass an earlier load of any type. Intel doesn't state this anywhere in the manual as far as I know.

Regarding examples 4a and 4b, Intel doesn't provide guarantees on the ordering between a WB load and a WC load. The AMD model allows a WC load to pass an earlier WB load, but not the other way around.