# MFENCE/LFENCE/SFENCE Behaviour Inside Function

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel, internals

What is the difference in behaviour between the MFENCE/LFENCE/SFENCE instruction as an intrinsic put right before the instruction it's meant to serialize (A) and the instruction inside a function that must be called before the instruction that needs to be serialized (B)?

So basically the difference between

(A):

```
LFENCE
RDTSC
```

(B):

```
Fence PROC
LFENCE
RET
Fence ENDP

...

CALL Fence
RDTSC
```

Comment: No difference, except that sfence or mfence would also serialize the write to the stack.

Comment: Why are you talking about intrinsics when you only have asm source code?  In asm you write *instructions* directly, without having to ask the compiler to generate the asm you want.  (See [When should I use \_mm\_sfence \_mm\_lfence and \_mm\_mfence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50780314) for an answer that's actually about intrinsics in C++, not asm directly.)

Comment: Also note that only LFENCE is guaranteed to serialize execution relative to RDTSC, because serializing instruction execution is part of LFENCE but not the others.  MFENCE does on some CPUs as an implementation details, and SFENCE does on some other CPUs (maybe AMD).

Comment: @prl: sfence wouldn't serialize call's store relative to rdtsc.  Think of it like a grocery-store checkout conveyor belt divider for the store buffer; it doesn't block retirement or exec in the ROB, only serializes L1d commit order.  (IIRC it's stronger on AMD CPUs, but it's not true in general across x86, and this question is even tagged [intel] for some reason.)  [Why is (or isn't?) SFENCE + LFENCE equivalent to MFENCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322404)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what's exactly is in the `Fence` function. In particular, it depends what's between the fence and the `rdtsc`. It also depends on what's after `rdtsc`.

Consider the `lfence` case and where `rdtsc` is at the top of the timed region. Since `Fence` is being called using the `call` instruction, there is probably a `ret` at the end of that function to go back to the following `rdtsc`. This means that there is at least a `ret` between the `lfence` and the `rdtsc`. Most probably the `ret` here is of the form C3, which gets decoded and allocated into the reservation station as two uops on modern Intel and AMD processors. These uops are used to load the return address from the stack and verify the prediction, so there is a true data dependency between them and current processors don't use value prediction.

If the load hits in the L1D and the DTLB or STLB, or if the value is forwarded from the store buffer (this is possible because `lfence` doesn't wait for the store buffer to drain), it's unlikely that there will be a difference between having `lfence` placed immediately before `rdtsc` and having a `ret` between the two instructions. But if the load takes a long time, `rdtsc` may have already been executed and later instructions would be in-flight as well in the backend. After the load completes, there is still another uop from `ret` to be executed waiting in the RS. This uop consumes certain resources and could interfere with all the other uops that are in the timed region and may affect the measured time. Note that even with your simple `Fence` function, a hardware interrupt could occur just before `RET`, making store forwarding impossible and may end up evicting the return address from the L1D. Anyway, unless you hit a pathological instruction sequence in the timed region, this doesn't matter unless you really want extreme precision.

You'd normally want to place `lfence` immediately before `rdtsc`. You can use a macro instead of a function or force the compiler to inline the function if possible (but even then you still have to examine the generated asm code and make sure it's what you want).

`sfence` doesn't interact with `ret` or `rdtsc`, so there is no ordering effects with respect to these instructions. `mfence` forces the load from `ret` to wait until most earlier memory-related operations reach the point of global oveservability or persistence. `mfence` and `sfence` alone don't serialize `rdtsc`.

Comment: There's no data dependency between the `ret` and `rdtsc`, and nothing is blocking branch prediction / speculative execution.  (The return predictor should pretty definitely predict correctly unless there's an interrupt before the ret; this ret matches the last call).  So the call has to execute its push and jump uops before lfence.  If this call fence / rdtsc is at the bottom of a timed region, the call instruction is part of what's waited for but ret isn't.  If it's at the top, then there's a ret that can exec in parallel with getting the start time.

Comment: TL:DR: of what I meant to say: the `ret` is *after* the `lfence`, so the data dependency between its component uops shouldn't be relevant, except for which cycle it's going to need to run its port 6 (Intel) uop while the back-end is working on the `rdtsc` uops or uops of whatever real work follows.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah I've written the answer while only thinking about the case where `rdtsc` is at the top of the timed region. Even at the bottom could also interfere with the measurement. The call/ret could push `rdtsc` to the next group of uops to be allocated, for example.